# Analysing the behavior of a solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have this following ODE:

$$ \dot{x} = \frac{2x^4 + 2t}{3x^4 + 14} $$

where $x(0) = 0$. Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a solution to this ODE. How do I analyze the points where $\phi$ is decreasing or increasing? Its local maximum or minimum?

I've tried to obtain the solution to the ODE and then analyze its derivatives, but I don't think that this is the correct way to approach this problem. Is there a proper way to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Suppose that a solution $x(t)$ has a critical point at time $t_0$, that is, that $\dot x(t_0) = 0$. To determine the character of that critical point, we can apply the Second Derivative Test. Computing gives
$$\ddot x(t) = f(t) \dot x(t) + \frac{2}{3 x(t)^4 + 14}$$
for some function $f(t)$ defined on all of $\Bbb R$, so $$\ddot x(t_0) = \frac{2}{3 x(t_0)^4 + 14} > 0 ,$$ and in particular any critical point is a local minimum.

So far we have not used the initial condition, i.e., that the particular solution $\phi$ satisfies $\phi(0) = 0$ (so the above analysis incidentally applies to any initial condition). Does that condition give us information about the time of some minimum of $\phi$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Can you show me how you got  the $\frac{2}{3x(t)^4 + 14}$ part?

Comment: Is it correct to suppose that, given that $\phi(0) = 0$, $t_0 = 0 $ is a critical point of the function, using this information, we can apply the second derivative test on that point to find out that $0$ is a local minimum point. Is there a way to find the other critical points of  $\phi$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $\phi$ satisfies the differential equation and also $\phi(0) = 0$, substituting in the differential equation gives that $\dot \phi(0) = 0$, that is, $t = 0$ is a critical point of the function. Suppose any solution of the differential equation had $2$ critical points, say, $a, b$, where $a < b$; what could we say about the behavior of $\dot x$ on that interval? $\ddot x$? (We could consider just a solution $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(0) = 0$, but the same argument in fact applies to all solutions.)

Comment: As for the statement about $\ddot x(t_0)$, we just substituted $\dot x(t_0) = 0$ (i.e., the condition that $t_0$ is a critical point of $x(t)$) in the previous equation for $\ddot x(t)$.

Comment: yes, but why $\ddot{x}(t) = f(t)\dot{x}(t) + \frac{2}{3x(t)^4 + 14}$ and not $\ddot{x}(t) = f(t)\dot{x}(t) + \frac{2t + 3x(t)⁴}{3x(t)^4 + 14}$?

Comment: We can also say that the function is increasing given that  $\frac{2}{3x(t)^4 + 14}$ can not be negative because $3x(t)^4 > 0, \forall t$, we can manipulate the inequality to find the other critical points of $\phi$, right?

Comment: The form of the equation for $\ddot x$ is just given by differentiating the d.e. and collecting terms in $\dot x$: $$\ddot x = \underbrace{\frac{8 (14 - 3 t) x^3}{(3 x^4 + 14)^2}}_f \dot x + \frac{2}{3 x^4 + 14} .$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd manipulate that particular inequality. To rephrase my above hint: Suppose we had $2$ distinct critical points, $a, b$, $a < b$. We know that they are both minima. What does $x$ look like on the interval $[a, b]$?

Comment: $x$ is increasing, right?

Comment: I see it now, $x$ is always increasing in $[0,\infty]$, but what about $[-\infty, 0]$? Are  there any critical points in this interval?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145531/discussion-between-occhima-and-travis-willse).

Answer (score 1):

The naivest way is to consider $t \in [-10,10]$, set $\Delta t \equiv \color{green}{\pm} 10/20$ and apply *Euler's method*:

$$
\begin{cases}
t_0 = 0 \\
x_0 = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
t_i = t_{i-1} + \Delta t \\
x_i = x_{i-1} + \frac{2x_{i-1}^4+2t_{i-1}}{3x_{i-1}^4+14}\,\Delta t \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \quad \quad
i = 1,2,\dots,20
$$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

where I first applied $\color{green}{\pm}$ with the $\color{blue}{\text{minus sign}}$, then with the $\color{red}{\text{plus sign}}$.